# Facebook like button with different message

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

I'd like put the button on each products page on my webside.
Each button, after click should public different description on wall.
For example:

Product:
Price:
[LINK]

How could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a different message on the Facebook wall? If so, I generally use [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) as a quick solution. Just follow the instructions on there and implement the relevant code on every page/into your CMS.

Comment: Yes, I mean a different message on the Facebook wall.
After click, customer should see on his wall dynamicly generated text like: Product: ... , Price: ... , [URL]

Comment: Okay cool! In that case, AddThis will generate the Facebook Wall Post, based on what is on the page. Give it a go, and let me know how it goes! You may have to play with the meta tags to get what you want though e.g. adding price to the meta tags on your web pages.